# Receber valor booleano via javaScript num popUp para ser usado em outra pagina

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, popup

Tenho uma pagina que abre um popUp de confirmação, o popUp é chamado com o  `window.showModalDialog`, preciso pegar true ou false desse popUp, para trabalhar na pagina 1 onde o valor devolvido será usado, mas não estou conseguindo, me indicaram usar o `window.open` ao invés do  `window.showModalDialog`, ele até abre o popUp mas não retorna o valor, mas não funciona, estou usando VB.Net

```
//Pagina 1
var Retorno = window.showModalDialog("../Popup/FramePop.aspx?Pagina=PopConfirmacao.aspx")

document.getElementById('idAquiDoElemento').value = Retorno;

//javaScript do botão confirmar no popUp aberto em outra página aspx

function ConfirmarDados(acao, document)
{

            window.returnValue = acao;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Já consegui, passei uma funcao javaScript via url ao abrir o popUp, e depois na função do popUp eu consegui acessar e trabalhar o valor nela.

//Pagina 1

function FnAtualiza(retorno) {
            document.getElementById('idAquiDoElemento').value = retorno;

```
        return retorno;
    }
```

var Retorno = window.showModalDialog("../Popup/FramePop.aspx?Pagina=PopConfirmacao.aspx", { confirmaContatoCallback: FnAtualiza})

document.getElementById('idAquiDoElemento').value = Retorno;

//javaScript do botão confirmar no popUp aberto em outra página aspx

function ConfirmarDados(acao)
{

```
       var dialogArguments = window.dialogArguments;
        dialogArguments.confirmaContatoCallback(acao);
        window.close();
```

}